# jquery.ajax with php

Tags: php

I have just started working on php. It's a very good lang as I'm feeling but some point I get stuck as I'm new to this.

My javascript code

```
var pv = $("#txtStart").val();
var av = $("#txtStartNextLevel").val();
var au = $("#fileStartPlay").val();
alert(pv+" "+av+" "+au);
var myau = au.split('\\');
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:php_url,
    data:"{startPoint:"+pv+"nextLevelPoint:"+av+"audioFile:"+myau[myau.length-1]+"}",
    contentType:"application/json",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(){
        alert("done");
    },
    error:function(){
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

My PHP code.

```
<?php
    if(file_exists("Text.txt"))
    {
        $fileName = "Text.txt";
        $fh = fopen($fileName,"a")

        $Starts = $_POST["startPoint"];
        $NextLevel = $_POST["nextLevelPoint"];
        $AudioFileName = $_POST["audioFile"];
            $code .=$Starts."*".$NextLevel."_1*".$AudioFileName."\"";
            fwrite($fh,$code);
        fclose($fh);   
    }
?>
```

When I run this it executes but doesn't write the values in the variable

```
$Starts,$NextLevel,$AudioFileName**.
```

And further if I write the same ajax procedure in

```
$.post(php_url,{startPoint:pv,nextLevelPoint:av,audioFile:myau[myau.length-1]},function(data){});
```

this works fine and write the content in the file.

Also As I'm using post method it should not display the values in Address bar what I'm passing to write. But it's showing those values in both the method.

```
localhost://myphp.php?txtStart=Start&fileStartPlay=aceduos.jpg&txtStartNextLevel=adfd
```

Please guide me where I'm lacking...

Comment: assign objects to the `data` in your ajax function

Answer (score 3):

Replace the value bellow (with quotas)

```
"{startPoint:"+pv+"nextLevelPoint:"+av+"audioFile:"+myau[myau.length-1]+"}"
```

to

```
{startPoint:pv, nextLevelPoint: av, audioFile: myau[myau.length-1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do what Burak TAMTURK said, and also get rid of

```
contentType:"application/json",
```

$_POST data should be in content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is the default.